# How do I get meteor shell output to be more verbose?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am using meteor shell, however, it seems to hide certain details, making it a pain to inspect.

```
> Meteor.users.find().fetch()
{
  "_id": "someidgoeshere",
  "emails": [ [Object] ],
  "profile": {},
  "services": [ [Object] ]
}
```

I looked into the source and [found a REPL](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/tools/server/shell-server.js), checked the `.help` prompt. I looked in the [documentation and didn't even find "shell" listed in the CLI](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/commandline).

Is there a way to run Meteor shell with some sort of verbose option, such that it displays ALL the json?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to display all the data as JSON, there's a simple trick:

```
JSON.stringify(Meteor.users.find().fetch());
```

You will lose syntax colouration and functions though. I'm looking forward to a way to do it with the shell itself!

Comment: yeah there's plenty of "hacky" ways around it, but none that just seem simple and straight forward as intended, and can't find any docs on it

Comment: For good formatting, do `JSON.stringify(Meteor.users.find().fetch(), undefined, 2);`