# How to get Meteor shell to show entire object?

Tags: meteor

When I type this in `meteor shell` this is all I see:

```
> Meteor.users.find({username: "test"}).fetch()
[ { _id: 'rKAAq3koteTGQZyey',
    createdAt: Mon Oct 05 2015 15:24:55 GMT+1300 (NZDT),
    services: { password: [Object] },
    username: 'test',
    emails: [ [Object] ],
    profile: { services: [Object] } } ]
>
```

I want to see what's inside `[Object]`

I'd really hate to have to resort to just making everything into JSON:

[How do I get meteor shell output to be more verbose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783918/how-do-i-get-meteor-shell-output-to-be-more-verbose)

```
> JSON.stringify(Meteor.users.find().fetch(), undefined, 2);
'[\n  {\n    "_id": "rAw9EHxEdMFho2yvc",\n    "createdAt": "2015-10-05T01:51:18.103Z",\n    "services": {\n      "password": {\n        "bcrypt": "$2a$10$UN5JtVvFtgZ4rfuwSSGPDOtMRIUBVR9QCSWvEOPAFkTqteQhCO8wi"\n      },\n      "resume": {\n        "loginTokens": [\n          {\n            "when": "2015-10-05T01:51:50.198Z",\n            "hashedToken": "KmmMczQ6R6kwkQWuQdRR8wlrvSwNW12LsGDsoeDfZ3Q="\n          }\n        ]\n      }\n    },\n    "username": "admin",\n    "emails": [\n      {\n        "address": "admin@example.com",\n        "verified": false\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    "_id": "PxYZ5ACGgYC7ZJXnB",\n    "createdAt": "2015-10-05T01:51:18.230Z",\n    "services": {\n      "password": {\n        "bcrypt": "$2a$10$CUqmJq8yhbvWSIEQBUwPv.dGLx16kckhL3Xz2eGl8QyyI.gIiFF8q"\n      }\n    },\n    "username": "alex",\n    "emails": [\n      {\n        "address": "alex@example.com",\n        "verified": false\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    "_id": "ZpyAMTdwNzeBMLZuc",\n    "createdAt": "2015-10-05T01:51:18.342Z",\n    "services": {\n      "password": {\n        "bcrypt": "$2a$10$BUs2mCOXxmQPBvFpkUgIWO8RCsJh9OQphtMc5Eg7Fb2S1yIBG2NFu"\n      }\n    },\n    "username": "ana",\n    "emails": [\n      {\n        "address": "ana@example.com",\n        "verified": false\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    "_id": "MqipzbhRpJmv5sqww",\n    "createdAt": "2015-10-05T01:51:18.534Z",\n    "services": {\n      "password": {\n        "bcrypt": "$2a$10$Ltgla017NQkJDlvlltQ1TOjNQ7FUv92kgOUa6bCh2lwRQpqsMRr.i"\n      }\n    },\n    "username": "jose",\n    "emails": [\n      {\n        "address": "jose@example.com",\n        "verified": false\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    "_id": "T8ggaDgaSmWANbDmk",\n    "createdAt": "2015-10-05T01:51:18.678Z",\n    "services": {\n      "password": {\n        "bcrypt": "$2a$10$C7Wg4l87ALPaq/8Uhjo8FOnCBhw9n5qoyEkJkq9FzxM5./XU8NzSa"\n      }\n    },\n    "username": "anthony",\n    "emails": [\n      {\n        "address": "anthony@example.com",\n        "verified": false\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    "_id": "rKAAq3koteTGQZyey",\n    "createdAt": "2015-10-05T02:24:55.162Z",\n    "services": {\n      "password": {\n        "bcrypt": "$2a$10$aYBlVYJhl1vS8iDYF6nuUObYDTK6prfUtaqL9ao0Hq7uX863IyTa."\n      }\n    },\n    "username": "test",\n    "emails": [\n      {\n        "address": "test@example.com",\n        "verified": false\n      }\n    ],\n    "profile": {\n      "services": [\n        {\n          "hdrPhotos": 100\n        }\n      ]\n    }\n  }\n]'
>
```

Comment: What fields do you think it is missing? All the open and closing brackets match up, it's a valid object.

Comment: Agree, that looks like a complete, valid object

Comment: Hmmmm... I could have sworn that I added a `profile` field when I created the user.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$ meteor mongo
```

This will give you direct access to the mongo db. Then you can just do:

```
db.users.findOne({username: "test"})
```

and you'll get the whole object laid out for you.

Comment: findOne()'s output is nicely indented, but db.users.find()'s output is not pretty printed.

Comment: Because it's a cursor. If you want to pretty-print it, use a `.forEach()` loop on the cursor and `findOne()` inside that loop. `db.users.find({}).forEach(function(u){db.users.findOne({_id: u._id})});`

Comment: yeah I know.  I don't think we're really going to get an ideal answer for the OP, just workarounds...

Answer (score 0):

For good formatting, do

```
JSON.stringify(Meteor.users.find().fetch(), undefined, 2);
```

Comment: It looks to be even messier - see the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
function printObj(obj){
  console.log( JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
}
```

then:

```
printObj(Meteor.users.find().fetch())
```

Your output will not be in the shell, but in the server log, but will return all the data you want.